# tsc cannot find name <...> when transpiling electron app

Tags: typescript, electron, tsconfig

I'm trying to add typescript to an existing electron app. Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

When I try to transpile the app by running the "tsc" command, I get lots of the following errors:

> node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:8:20 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
> 8 type GlobalEvent = Event & { returnValue: any };
>
> node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:5203:59 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MessagePort'.
> 5203     postMessage(channel: string, message: any, transfer?: MessagePort[]): void;
>
> ...

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the "dom" library to the tsconfig.json as shown in [this GitHub post.](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/27092#issuecomment-749917155)
Here is my new tsconfig.json:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: TypeScript reference: [`compilerOptions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#compilerOptions) -> [`lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib)